# Filtering with Like operator on integer column

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, mikro-orm

I'm using `mikro-orm` for db related opeartions. My db entity has a number field:

```
@Property({ defaultRaw: 'srNumber', type: 'number' })
 srNumber!: number;
```

and corresponding db column (Postgresql) is:

```
srNumber(int8)
```

The query input for `where` param in `mikro-orm EntityRepository's findAndCount(where, option)` is:

```
repository.findAndCount({"srNumber":{"$like":"%1000%"}}, options)
```

It translates to:

```
select * from table1 where srNumber like '%1000%'
```

The problem here is since `srNumber` column is not a string, there is a type-mismatch and query fails. Casting it like `CAST(srNumber AS TEXT) like '%1000%'` should work in db.

Is there any way to somehow specify the field casting here?

Comment: As an aside, are you sure that that column is a number (i.e. something you do arithmetic with) rather than a string that only contains digit characters?

Comment: A string that only contains digits, yes. @muistooshort NOt used in numeric operations.

Comment: You might want to change the column type then; things like phone numbers, SSNs, and zip codes look like numbers but they're not really numbers. That you're doing LIKEs on these values suggests that they're not really numbers even if they look like numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom SQL fragments in the query. To get around strictly typed `FilterQuery`, you can use `expr` which is just an identity function (returns its parameter), so have effect only for TS checks.

Something like this should work:

```
import { expr } from '@mikro-orm/core';

const res = await repo.findAndCount({
  [expr('cast(srNumber as text)')]: { $like: '%1000%' },
}, options);
```

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/entity-manager/#using-custom-sql-fragments